# Azure Web Role Availibility status in Dashboard

Tags: azure, dashboard, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I wanted to create an Azure Dashboard which showed me some information about my Azure cloud services. The basic metrics is easy to add to Azure Dashboard but I kind of stuck of showing the Availibility status of each web roles to the dashboard.

Eventually I want this table (screenshot is from the blade of the cloud service)
[image]

To somehow integrate in my Azure Dashboard. Tried everything in Azure metrics or inside the blade. One possibility is to use kusto language to get the status through app insights. But that's some over my head kind of language; And I don't know if that even works. Of course why re-invent the wheel when someone already has tried this. So here comes my question. Does someone already tried this out or know if this could be possible throug app insighs log queries  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the the Azure Dashboard [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations) your scenario is currently not possible. "No support for querying across multiple workspaces or Application Insights applications."